# Open Report with Button based on Checkbox Value

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms, ms-access-reports

I have a button that is already assigned to open a Report. What I want is that when the user enables a checkbox, I want the `OnClick` action of the button that I already assigned to change to open a different report.

So my logic goes like this:

```
button 1 = docmd.openreport 
when user checkbox = true 
button 1 = docmd.openreport2
```

Is that possible?

```
Private Sub Check130_Click()
    If Me.Check130.Value = True Then
    Me.Command1871.OnClick() = DoCmd.OpenReport "rptLoansNew", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
End Sub
```

But it show syntax error.

In fact I'm clueless how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub YourButton_Click()

    Dim ReportName As String

    If Me!Check130.Value = True Then
        ReportName = "rptLoansNew"
    Else
        ReportName = "rptLoansOld"
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewReport, "", "", acNormal

End Sub
```

And do rename your controls to something meaningful.

Comment: It's not exactly what i was looking for but it worked like a charm.